# NodeJS - OpenCV error :- libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, linux, opencv

I'm trying to install OpenCV in NodeJS, but I'm getting error.
Even though I have installed OpenCV on my Linux machine (Linux Mint Cinnamon).
Error:

> libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my Linux Machine (Arch Linux). Installing opencv2 (er downgrading to opencv2) worked for me.